# ESPAsyncWebServer on ESP32 serving CaptivePortal Issue with displaying images

Tags: esp32

Im trying to make a captive portal that serves index.html that displays images from device.

If I connect ESP32 to wifi AP and access it directly images display as intended but if I set it up as Captive portal images dont display.

Do I need to hardcode routes to every image?

Comment: Show us some code. If you use captive portal, there is an other handler for the routes.